# In Rampage, Kate Caldwell was trying to cure her brother

Tags: rampage

She started out working for Claire Wyden, head of the genetics company Energyne. Initially, she accepted it in an attempt to save her sick brother. Unfortunately, she was framed by her evil boss before she could finish her research and arrested.
Who saved Kate’s brother if Kate herself was in jail?

Comment: Didn't her brother die while she was in jail?

Comment: Because of negligence by his new carer, or committed suicide like Raleigh in Would You Rather?